# Recharts - align axis label in the left side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am creating a horizontal bar graph using `recharts` library. I want to align the y-axis label in the left side.

```
<BarChart width={400} height={300} data={data} layout="vertical" margin={{right: 40}}>
   <XAxis hide axisLine={false} type="number"/>
   <YAxis dataKey="name" type="category" axisLine={false} tickLine={false} />
   <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" barSize={15} radius={[20,20,20,20]} fill="#8884d8" background={{fill: "#eee", radius: [20,20,20,20]}} tick={false} />
   <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" barSize={15} radius={[20,20,20,20]} fill="#eee" >
     <LabelList dataKey="amt" position="right" />
   </Bar>
</BarChart>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3macevm/13/)

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by `align`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: In the fiddle for the 2nd and 3rd bar, their labels 'B', 'C' should be aligned on the left side(below the first character of bar1's label i.e below 'P')

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by using a custom Tick component.

```
const CustomYAxisTick = React.createClass({
    render() {
        const { x, y, payload } = this.props;
        return (<g transform={`translate(${0},${y})`}>
            <text x={0} y={0}
                textAnchor="start"
                fill="#666">{payload.value}</text>
        </g>)
    }
})
```

And then you can use that in your YAxis:

```
<YAxis tick={<CustomYAxisTick />} />
```

I forked your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheSwedishChef/qmw6oxsy/1/) and added those changes.